# Uniform Cost Search with Backtracking / Additional constraint?

Tags: graphs, artificial-intelligence

I am able to implement the default uniform cost search (python) to find the shortest path between two nodes (path cost). I followed this pseudocode:

[image]

Now, I want to calculate the shortest path **with fuel constraint**.

Each edge in the graph is associated with a pair of values (, ) where  denotes the distance and  denotes the
fuel cost.

[image]

The job is to find the shortest path between  and 
such that the accumulated fuel cost along the path does not exceed a fuel budget. Specifically,
we want to find the shortest path from S to T not exceeding a fuel budget
11. We can observe that although the path S->2->T has the shortest travel distance 10, its accumulated
fuel cost 12 exceeds the fuel budget 11. Thus, this path is infeasible. In this example, the path
S->1->T is the shortest feasible path.

What approach should I use for my current UCS algorithm?

Following the original algorithm, it is only adding the neighbor node to the queue if it's not already in the queue, or if the one in the queue has a larger accumulative distance, then I update it with the current shorter accumulative distance. This means at any time, the queue will only have one instance of the node.

Now with this additional fuel cost budget/constraint, what should I modify? Does it seem that now there could be more than one instance of the node with different fuel costs and distance in the queue?

Comment: What does the "fuel cost" mean and how does it affect the "fuel budget"?  I think you'll need to define the problem more carefully.  Under what conditions is a path allowable?  Must the sum of the fuel costs be at most the fuel budget?  Is the fuel cost per unit distance or total for the entire edge?

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your reply. The fuel cost is the amount of fuel spent to travel between two nodes e.g to get from node A to B, the fuel costs 2. To get from node B to C, the fuel costs 1. Hence to get from A to C, the accumulative fuel cost would be 3

Comment: A shortest path is allowable if the accumulated fuel cost does not exceed the fuel budget. You are right, sum of the fuel costs must be at most the fuel budget. The fuel cost is not per unit distance, it is given for the entire edge

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments -- instead, [edit] the question so the question is clear for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Thank you!

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, I suggest putting that in an answer, rather than in a comment.  The Stack Exchange model works better when this kind of thing goes in an answer rather than a comment, as people can upvote it, the question can be treated as answered in a search, etc.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove most of the content after receiving an answer.

Comment: @D.W. the answer does not help this problem. this apparently is a simple modified disjktra. I cannot select this answer as it's misleading for this particular problem

Comment: If that answer is not satisfactory, I suggest first making sure your question is clear about the problem statement, then leaving a comment on the answer explaining the problem with it and how you know it does not solve the problem.

Comment: the question is clear,i even provided images and statements. I do not wish to continue further with this post. If anyone else is reading, don't bother with this. This turns out to not be too complex of a problem that some are suggesting it to be

Answer (score 2):

The problem is known as the *constrained shortest path problem*. It is known to be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. The proof is given in the paper: "[A dual algorithm for the constrained shortest path problem](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/net.3230100403)" (by Gabriel Y. Handler and Israel Zang)

You may want to check this survey for solutions: "[A survey of resource-constrained shortest path problems: Exact solution approaches](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/net.21511)" (by Luigi Di Puglia Pugliese and Francesca Guerriero)